# Unable to change the elements in an array using a function

Tags: c++

I have been working on a project for school to develop a poker game.  I have the code that randomly generates the cards, but I am having problems using functions to sort them.  I believe the algorithm itself works, but I am not sure about how to properly access the variables in an array. Visual Studio gives me the errors `argument of type "int (*)[5]` is incompatible with parameter of type `int *(*)[5]` and `'void sortPokerHand(int *[][5])': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int [2][5]' to 'int *[][5]'`.

The declaration of pokerHand within main()

```
int pokerHand[2][5];
```

My functions

```
//swap the two values
void swap(int* pokerHand, int* x, int* y)
{
  int tempVal = pokerHand[0][x];
  int tempSuit = pokerHand[1][x];
  pokerHand[0][x] = pokerHand[0][y];
  pokerHand[1][x] = pokerHand[1][y];
  pokerHand[0][y] = tempVal;
  pokerHand[1][y] = tempSuit;
}

void sortPokerHand(int* pokerHand[2][5])
{
   //bubble sort poker hand
   bool swapped;
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
      swapped = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < (5 - i - 1); j++)
      {
        if (pokerHand[0][j] > pokerHand[0][j + 1])
        {
            swap(pokerHand[2][5], pokerHand[0][j], pokerHand[0][j + 1]);
            swapped = true;
        }
      }

      // If no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break 
      if (swapped == false)
        break;
   }
}
```

How I am attempting to use the function

```
sortPokerHand(pokerHand);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Most of this is wrong. `int* pokerHand[2][5]` is an array of 2 arrays of 5 `int` pointers. The `*` shouldn't be there. You're passing `int` to the swap function which is declared to take `int*`, then in that function treating it like `int (*)[n]`, where `n` should be `int`, but you're using `int*`. In short, there isn't much that *doesn't* need fixing. If this doesn't spew compiler warnings you seriously need to turn up your warning levels to pedantic heights.

Comment: "//bubble sort poker hand" - *Why*? What's wrong with `std::sort`?

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much, much harder than it should be. Consider the following pre-conditions:

- A "hand" is a sequence of five `int` values
- Only cards in a single hand are sorted relative to each other.

Given that, your `swap` routine is completely wrong. It should take two `int` by address (so, pointers to `int`), and use those to swap contents:

```
void swapInt(int *left, int *right)
{
    int tmp = *left;
    *left = *right;
    *right = tmp;
}
```

Next, when sorting, we're sorting a *single* hand. That means a *single* sequence of five `int`. Therefore, there is no need to pass arrays of arrays, pointers to arrays, arrays of pointers, or any of that. Just do this, clean and basic:

```
// assumption: a hand has five cards
void sortPokerHand(int hand[])
{
    // bubble sort sequence of int
    size_t len = 5;
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped && len-- > 0)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if (hand[i] > hand[i + 1])
            {
                swapInt(hand + i, hand + i + 1); // note: uses our new swap function
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, we need somehands, both needing sorting. For the sake of this example I'm declaring them in `main()` as inline array of arrays, then making two calls to actually sort them, one at a time. First, however, we need a print function:

```
void printHand(const int hand[])
{
    fputc('{', stdout);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%d ", hand[i]);
    puts("}");
}
```

Simple enough. Now `main()`

```
int main()
{
    int  hands[2][5] = 
    {
        { 5,10,7,4,1 },
        { 3,6,8,2,9 }
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        sortPokerHand(hands[i]);
        printHand(hands[i]);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
{1 4 5 7 10 }
{2 3 6 8 9 }
```

Exactly as we expect.

That's it. In more general solutions we would have an arbitrary hand-size an have to ripple that through the sort and print functions to ensure complete and proper activity. Knowing it is statically size five makes that a little easier.

Also note that you can completely change the definition of `hands` to use pointers-to-arrays rather than arrays of arrays, or even pointers to pointers, and it will still work, so long as the thing going to `sortHand` and/or `printHand` is `int*` pointing to five `int` values.

Answer (score 0):

The real question would be how you're ending up with something like `int *pokerHand[2][5]` in the first place.

One of the strengths of C++ is a fairly rich type system. If I were doing this, I'd probably start by defining a type for a card:

```
class card {
    enum { clubs, diamonds, spades, hearts } suit;
    int value; // 1-13 = Ace - King
public:
    bool operator<(card const &other) { 
        if (suit < other.suit)
            return true;
        if (other.suit < suit)
            return false;
        return value < other. value;
    }
};
```

So, that `operator<` sorts first by suit, then by value within the suit, so all the cards in the same suit will get sorted together.

From there, a poker hand is typically going to be five cards, so we just have:

```
std::vector<card> poker_hand;
```

Sorting the hand is something like:

```
std::sort(poker_hand.begin(), poker_hand.end());
```

If you want to write your own sort routine you obviously can, but it still ends up pretty trivial--a single-dimension vector of cards, which you just compare directly, such as:

```
if (secondCard < firstCard) 
    swap(secondCard, firstCard);
```

Answer (score -1):

Change int* pokerHand[2][5] to int** pokerHand.

Comment: Probably still will not work. `int [][]` is not compatible with `int**`

Comment: Went with probably because I didn't see the definition of `pokerHand` in the question. `int pokerHand[2][5];` certainly will not fit in `int**`.

Comment: @user4581301 Look near the top of the question.